# Azure Web App usage of WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME variable in docker-compose

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, devops

I'm trying to set up a web app that has persistent storage via file share to a storage account.

I'm following various guides from Microsoft docs and I managed to do most of it, my app has persisted storage. But now, what I wanna do, I want to map volumes to my storage account.

I saw that there is this variable `${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}` that I can use in my docker-compose.

My question is, what is the value of this variable? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app#modify-configuration-file) state:

> `${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}` is an environment variable in App Service that is mapped to persistent storage for your app.

I find this a little vague. Does it know automatically to map my path mappings? What if I have multiple path mappings? Should I set the value in the App Settings in the `Configuration` blade? If so, what do I need to specify, the mount path?

Besides that, I saw that it is used as following:

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
   wordpress:
     image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/multicontainerwordpress
     volumes:
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/site/wwwroot:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
```

I'm used with named volumes in docker-compose. I figure there is no need to specify something like that?

**UPDATE**
After @Jason Pan's answer, I tried to play with the mount a little bit.

I succeeded in having persisted storage on the App Service with the following docker-compose:

```yaml
# ... lines skipped for brevity
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

volumes:
  mysql-data:
    driver: local
```

But I want to persist the data on a Storage Account. I saw that this is possible via: `AppService/Configuration/Path Mappings`.

My Docker Compose

```yaml
# ...
    volumes:
      - MyMountedPath:/var/lib/mysql
```

In this docker-compose file, I have my app and a MySQL image: `mysql:8` to be exact.

I mounted a path as follows:
`Name: MyMountedPath; Mounted Path: /usr/local/mysql; Type: Azure Files ...`.

And I get the following error in the logs:

> 2021-04-08T11:02:06.790578922Z chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted

> 2021-04-08T11:02:12.785079208Z 2021-04-08 11:02:12+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.

Since it worked with the first approach, I suspect that there are some issues with the way my Path mapping is defined. This led me to even more questions:

- Does my Mount Path need to exist on the App Service File system? If no, can I define something like: `/foo/bar` ?
- If I have a Mount Path name `MyMountedPath`, can I specify in the docker-compose file something like

```yaml
volumes:
  - MyMountedPath/foo:/something
```

Basically, navigating in the mounted path?

- Do I need to mount this path in the File Storage in my Storage Account? Or will the App Service create this path when it will need to store something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Example:
> In the App Service properties, I mounted an Azure File Share and gave the name 
> MyExternalStorage 
> In the docker compose configuration I have to set 
> volumes:
> - MyExternalStorage:/var/www/html/contao

Thanks for TeddyDubois29's answer, hope it also can help you.

[Web App Docker Compose Persistent Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/95785/web-app-docker-compose-persistent-storage.html)

**Like below**

When mounting an Azure File on the App service, a name is chosen for the mount.

This name is the reference for the Volumes parameter in the config file.

Example:

In the App Service properties, I mounted an Azure File Share and gave the name MyExternalStorage

In the docker compose configuration I have to set

volumes:

```
MyExternalStorage:/var/www/html/contao
```

Comment: So it did kinda work, in my sense that the containers start but I have a MySQL image which throws the following errors: `2021-04-08T10:56:54.313761397Z chown: changing ownership of '/var/lib/mysql/': Operation not permitted
2021-04-08T10:57:01.135148684Z 2021-04-08 10:57:01+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.23-1debian10 started.`

Comment: I managed to make it work somehow. Now I'm having some strange error where both my containers start successfully but the app service stops them for some weird reason. Anyway, your answer led me to figure it out.

Comment: Please don't just do a link like this, it might die in the future...