# azure shared storage file not found

Tags: azure-web-app-service, containers

In this project I am using azure app service with linux containers, there is a certain file that must persist and be shared across all the instances. However when the container starts it fails with the following error

```
Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
```

Using File Zilla and the app service FTPS credentials I am able to upload the file I need to the default shared storage ending in this folder structure

```
-/
 |_ASP.NET
 |_LogFiles
 |_site
 |_thefileineed.txt
```

As you can see, is a c# project, so it has an appsettings.json file in which the path to this file is declared

```
{
   "PathToFile":"/home/thefileineed.txt"
}
```

Because it uses containers I asume that i must mount the shared storage inside the container with compose-file.yml and following the documentation I use the following setup:

```
...
volumes:
- ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}:/home
```

What i am missing? or how is it supposed to access to the file

Answer (score 0):

Your setting  should be like below.

> MyExternalStorage
> In the docker compose configuration I have to set
> ......
> volumes:
> - MyExternalStorage:/var/www/html/contao

**For more details, please read related posts.**

[1. Azure Web App usage of WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME variable in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993860/azure-web-app-usage-of-webapp-storage-home-variable-in-docker-compose/66996132#66996132)

[2. [ Q&A ] Web App Docker Compose Persistent Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/95785/web-app-docker-compose-persistent-storage.html)