# Azure App Service "Bind mount must start with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}"

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I tried running this inside a docker compose file.

```
image: nginx:latest 
ports:
  - 80:80 
volumes:
  - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

However, I'm getting "`Bind mount must start with ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}.`" I tried adding ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME} but then receive: "`invalid volume specification`"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Web App usage of WEBAPP\_STORAGE\_HOME variable in docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993860/azure-web-app-usage-of-webapp-storage-home-variable-in-docker-compose)